# How to add initialization code to SWIG Python extension

Tags: python-2.7, swig

I created a Python extension to a C++ library.

How do I add code to the interface file, to be executed when the module is loaded/imported ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Use %init tag as described in: [SWIG Basics - Code insertion](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn44)